# Handling Camera Permission Result - Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, camera, runtime, android-camera

I am using below method to check whether Camera permission is granted or not:

```
//Global variable
int cameraPermission = -1;

Future<void> checkCameraPermission() async {
cameraPermissionStatus = await Permission.camera.status;
print(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>\ncamera permission >> " +
    cameraPermissionStatus.name);
if (cameraPermissionStatus.name == "granted") {
  cameraPermission = 1;
  scheduleTimeout(4 * 1000);
} else if (cameraPermissionStatus.name == "denied") {
  cameraPermission = 2;
} else {
  cameraPermission=0;
}
    setState(() {});
}
```

calling above method in `initState()` inside **addPostFrameCallback**

Reflecting view in build method as below:

```
return Column(
            children: [
              cameraPermission==1
                  ? Expanded(flex: 2, child: buildCameraPreview())
                  : cameraPermission==2
                      ? Container(
                          child: InkWell(
                          onTap: () async {
                            await Permission.camera.request();
                          },
                          child: Padding(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 200.h),
                              child: Text(
                                  "Tap here to grant Camera Permission")),
                        ))
                      : cameraPermission==0
                          ? Center(
                              child: InkWell(
                              onTap: () {
                                openAppSettings();
                              },
                              child: Text(
                                  "Tap here to grant Camera permission\nfrom application Settings"),
                            ))
                          : Container(),
```

The Issue is by default is displays "denied" view (cameraPermission==2) which is okay, But since I have called **checkCameraPermission** method in init inside **addPostFrameCallback**,

It should reflect once I grant or allow camera permission from opened permission dialog but it not reflecting view. After going back to previous screen and coming back its working.

What might be the issue? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're displaying Camera based on the value of `cameraPermission`, and you did not updated the `cameraPermission` variable once the user has granted the access.
Try setting `cameraPermission` to 1 inside setState.
Else try calling `await Permission.camera.request();` sindie the `addPostFrameCallBack`.

Answer (score 1):

The addPostFrameCallback will be called immediately after rendering that frame and your camera permission will be still denied. So either you need to request the permission in the `checkCameraPermission` method. Or call it after you request the permission.

```
Container(
   child: InkWell(
      onTap: () async {
         await checkCameraPermission();
      },
      child: Padding(
         padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 200.h),
         child: Text("Tap here to grant Camera Permission"),
      ),
   ),
),
```

And change the implementation like:

```
Future<void> checkCameraPermission() async {
   cameraPermissionStatus = await Permission.camera.request();
   print(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>\ncamera permission >> " + cameraPermissionStatus.name);
   if (cameraPermissionStatus.name == "granted") {
      cameraPermission = 1;
      scheduleTimeout(4 * 1000);
   } else if (cameraPermissionStatus.name == "denied") {
      cameraPermission = 2;
   } else {
      cameraPermission=0;
   }
   setState(() {});
}
```

Comment: and is it require audio permission also for Camera?

Comment: @JaiminModi I didn't get that question. In which platform iOS/Android ?

Comment: In Android. I have used this plugin :  camera: ^0.10.0+4 and it also asking for audio permission

Comment: @JaiminModi I guess it's for recording video. In Android 13 there are some permission changes.

Comment: Yes @JaiminModi you have require to give audio permission for use camera.